# Is it possible (& if so how) to create a programmable node-based flow diagram (in Visual Studio) like that in UE4?

Tags: c#, flowchart

I'm trying to create a programmable node-based flow diagram.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

-Create simple **nodes** like in the following diagram, within an **infinite workspace(like in UE4)**, in which each node contains **several parameters** like a name, image etc.

[image: Behaviour tree in UE4]

-Ability to connect the nodes using arrows which **snaps to the edges**, which defines the **flow** of the chart.

-Ability of **conditional selection** at branching nodes. (like selecting a dialogue choice)

-Print the stored Name string values in each nodes following the flow order.

-Show the text stored in a **desired node** using a message box, OnButtonClick event. (maybe the nodes are indexed).

for example,

```
    MessageBox.Show(getNode(i).getStoredNameText());
```

**My Question:**

Is such a task possible to do in Visual Studio 2017? If not, what software would you suggest?

Comment: Pretty much everything is possible if you put enough work into it.

Comment: @TaW Agree. Well you technically answered the question before editted :-) thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio is just an IDE, if you type something like "WPF node editor" into your favorite search engine you'll get plenty of hits that should give you the information you need to get started

Comment: @UnholySheep oops! I was trying winforms. Will definitely try WPF. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much to @TaW and @UnholySheep.

I achieved exactly what I needed using https://github.com/Wouterdek/NodeNetwork.

How did I miss that? Guess it was because I focused only on WinForms. But turns out WPF could do a lot more!